# nginx authorization based on client certificates

Tags: ssl, nginx, authorization

I have SSL enabled in nginx with the client certificate enabled in my browser.  With this I'm able to hit my site via HTTPS through port 443.

What I'm looking for now is to use this information about the client to allow access to different parts of the API (URLs) but deny access to other parts.  I can do this using IP address and the ngx_http_access_module with something like the following:

```
location /allowed/loc {
    allow 192.168.1.0/24;
}

location /protected/loc {
    allow 192.168.1.10;
    deny all;
}
```

What I'm looking for is some way to allow/deny based on the certificate of the client instead of on the IP address, ie something akin to this:

```
location /authorize/by/cert {
    allow client-cert-serial;
    deny all;
}
```

Is there a way to do this in nginx, or do I need to use something else?  Or am I thinking about this all wrong?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For access check you can use `if` directive and ssl module variables: `$ssl_client_s_dn`, `$ssl_client_serial`. Example

```
location /not/for/jhon/ {
   if ($ssl_client_s_dn ~ Jhon) {
      return 403;
   }
}
```

Good way to maintain list of allowed certificated the `map` directive. Example

```
map $ssl_client_s_dn $ssl_access {
default 0;
01 1;
02 1;
}

server {
  ...
  location /authorize/by/cert {
     if ($ssl_access = 0) {
        return 403;
     }
  }
}
```

or, rules can be more complicated

```
map $ssl_client_s_dn $ssl_access {
default "";
01 -a-b-c-;
02 -b-e-;
}

server {
  ...
  location /authorize/by/cert/a {
     if ($ssl_access !~ -a-) {
        return 403;
     }
  }

  location /authorize/by/cert/b {
     if ($ssl_access !~ -b-) {
        return 403;
     }
  }
}
```

But read this article before https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/. Use `if` only with `return` or `rewrite ... last;` directives.